# Pan frying store baught chicken breast with added glaze/broth solution

Tags: chicken, frying-pan, chicken-breast

When buying store bought chicken such as the one shown in the link below, a lot of times it comes with rib meat and glaze/solution to 'add flavor' etc. When defrosting the chicken breast and beginning to pan fry it with oil, the desired result is to get a golden brown / crispy chicken in the end.

Although the outcome always seem to be far from it with store bought varieties, as during the frying process, the juice/solutions comes out of the chicken breast to the point where the chicken breast which was suppose to be frying is now sitting in a puddle of a broth like solution.

As a result, I find myself spilling out the juices repeatedly throughout frying it, which is a huge turn off and a lot of times, it ends up being chewy as opposed to getting that pan fried effect.

I was just wondering if this is common for others cooking chicken breast as well and if there is any way to prepare store bought chicken breast, to prevent this from happening.

The chicken breast is something like this:

http://www.walmart.com/ip/Great-Value-All-Natural-Boneless-Skinless-Chicken-Breasts-5-lbs/36179444